# Does using an app send my IP address and device identification info to the app maker?

Tags: applications, privacy, network

if I use an app, would I be giving info like my IP address and device identification like the MAC address to the app developer/owner?

Comment: Are You asking about iOS or OS X?

Comment: It certainly could be the case. It depends on the app and if they collect such information. Your IP is public, so unless you use a Proxy server anyone can see it.

Comment: It indeed entirely depends on the app developer. Apple automatically sends reports to help with bug fixes. Also, when apps crash, you have a choice to send report to apple.

Comment: Also indicate which version of OS you are asking about. For example, early versions of iOS did allow access to MAC address, but the more recent versions including iOS 8 do not. IP address is always potentially available to any OS X or iOS app - most apps do use the internet and as a natural consequence of that communication, your IP address is known at the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the app. There's nothing that *by default* sends identifying in formation about your system to the App developers, the App would have to have been written in order to have this behavior. Depending on the app, however, it's possible that some might.

You didn't mention if you're on iOS or Mac OS. If you're on Mac OS, and you're concerned, or curious, you should consider installing an outgoing firewall like [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). What this will do is show an alert message asking for permission every time any app tries to send data to the Internet. You can use the Little Snitch network monitor to identify *what* data is being sent, to determine if your privacy is being violated. You can also prevent the app from sending data at all.

If you wanted to do the same for iOS you could use software on your router, but this is an advanced topic and beyond the scope of this answer.